# Java SpringBoot Spring Security: http.csrf().disable().build() Invalid CSRF-token

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf

Small question regarding Java SpringBoot + Spring Security app please.

I have a web app, which is designed as a server, to be called **only** by other servers.

There are **no webpages at all** involved, **no devices at all**, etc, it is a "server-to-server" communication only.

In order to secure my application, we leverage client certificate, and I did the following:

```
 @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        final ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager = authentication -> authenticate(authentication, subjectDnRegexAuthorizedList);
        return http.x509(x509 -> x509.principalExtractor(new SubjectDnX509PrincipalExtractor()).authenticationManager(authenticationManager)).authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges.anyExchange().authenticated()).build();
    }
```

(The details about the client certificate verification is not important to this question)

The thing is, when the caller calls into my app, it always, 100% of the time, gets 403 + Invalid CSRF-token, even with the correct client certificate.

I tried augmenting above snippet with `.csrf().disable()` and indeed, it works, I can get the request fine...

```
 @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        final ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager = authentication -> authenticate(authentication, subjectDnRegexAuthorizedList);
        return http.x509(x509 -> x509.principalExtractor(new SubjectDnX509PrincipalExtractor()).authenticationManager(authenticationManager)).authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges.anyExchange().authenticated()).csrf().disable().build();
    }
```

Unfortunately, **I do not wish to use** `.csrf().disable()`.

The callers, as many of them, cannot change, I cannot make all the callers to suddenly change / add something to perform CSRF. They all want to stick with client certificate only.

Question, why are we getting 403 + Invalid CSRF-token even if our auth is purely client certificate based?

How can I "bypass" this "Invalid CSRF-token", using only client certificate, without having to `.csrf().disable()` please?

Thank you

Comment: It looks like you don't understand the meaning of `.csrf().disable()`. It is the solution of your problem. The clients don't need to change anything. If you enable CSRF you need to change the clients. So what is the problem to disable it?

Comment: Please spend some time to read up on what a CSRF-token is, its purpose so you can decide if you want/need it instead of just saying `I do not wish to use .csrf().disable()`. Please motivate this statement